# VBA code not finding date with DateSerial() function for one computer but finding for another

Tags: excel, vba

I have two PC's with the same worksheet. My code can find the expected date in one of the computers but not in the other one

I tried to change date format on the PC that wasn't working and this solved my problem, but I need a code that runs always, not depending on Windows date format

```
Workbook2.Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
firstYear = Year(Cells(376, 2))
firstMonth = Month(Cells(376, 2))
firstDate = DateSerial(firstYear, firstMonth, 1)

Workbook1.Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Set oldforecast = Range("A9:A296").Find(firstDate)
```

The last line should find the date in Workbook1.xlsm for every computer that runs this code, despite it's date format.

Comment: Instead of `Find`, use `Application.Match` and convert the date to a `Long` first.

Comment: Also please check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba ;)